# Find volume of lesion mask

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging, software

I have drawn a lesion mask using FSLeyes on a T1-weighted image for MS patients. Is there tool to get the lesion volume from the mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your mask is in NIfTI format (nii or nii.gz extension), you can use the fslstats command line tool for that. Just type `fslstats` on the command line to see the help text for command syntax and arguments. For your specific case, you can use:

```
fslstats <input> -V
```

where `<input>` is the path to your mask NIfTI file. The returned numbers will be the mask volume in voxels and mm^3.

#### FSL install

Since you said you used FSLeyes to draw your mask, I'm assuming you have the full install of the FSL package as well. If not, see [their wiki for instructions](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation).